# Support Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What does |supp(p)| less than equal to |supp(q)| mean? Can someone please give an example. Here supp represents the support function
supp(p)= {z: p(z) > 0}

And it it true that|supp (p)| less that equal to |supp(q)| iff supp{alpha p+ (1- Alpha) r} less than equal to supp {alpha q + (1-alpha) q }?

Here p,q and r belong to [0,1]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't see a sence in the second question, because the support set is defined for functions, not for points of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $|\operatorname{supp} p|\le|\operatorname{supp}  q|$ means that the size (that is, cardinality) of the set $\operatorname{supp} p$ is not bigger than the size of the set  $\operatorname{supp} q$, that is there exists an injective map from $\operatorname{supp} p$ to $\operatorname{supp} q$.

For instance, let $X=\{0,1,2\} $, $p$ and $q$ be functions from $X$ to $\Bbb Z $ such that $p(0)=p(1)=0$, $p(2)=1$, $q(0)=0$, $q(1)=q(2)=1$ then $\operatorname{supp} p=\{1\}$, $\operatorname{supp} q=\{1,2\}$, so $|\operatorname{supp} p|=1\le 2=|\operatorname{supp}  q|$.

An other example. Let $X=\Bbb Z$ and $p$ and $q$ be functions from $X$ to $\Bbb Z $ such that for each $x\in X$ we have $p(x)=1$, if $x$ is even and  $p(x)=0$, otherwise; $q(x)=1$, if $x$ is divisible by three and  $q(x)=0$, otherwise.

Then  $\operatorname{supp} p=2\Bbb Z$, $\operatorname{supp} q=3\Bbb Z$, so $|\operatorname{supp} p|=\aleph_0=|\operatorname{supp} q|$, that is both $|\operatorname{supp} p|\le|\operatorname{supp}  q|$ and $|\operatorname{supp} q|\le|\operatorname{supp}  p|$.